# Layout Preview is not displaying layout when Material Design is added

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, material-design

I am working on an Android Application. Everything seems perfect until I decided to use **Material Design** in my theme. After adding **Material Design** Theme, layout preview is not displaying preview but works perfectly when build on the phone. Everything works perfectly when removing material design components used in xml.

Attaching my code:

**activity_home.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background"
        tools:context=".home.Home">


        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:text="LOG OUT"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
package com.****.*****.home;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.hashimshafiq.prepup.R;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity  {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.logout) void onClickLogout(){

    }


}
```

**build.graple (app module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.****.*****"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.2.0'
}
```

**build.gradle (Prepup)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>


    <style name="AppTextField" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/background</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@android:color/white</item>


    </style>




</resources>
```

The error that mostly occurred in Layout Preview

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@b83d5b8
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor509.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)
>       at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)
>       at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
>       at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
>       at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)
>       at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
>       at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction(ValueAnimator.java:674)
>       at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:637)
>       at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1069)
>       at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1088)
>       at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:852)
>       at android.animation.ValueAnimator.startWithoutPulsing(ValueAnimator.java:1081)
>       at android.animation.AnimatorSet.handleAnimationEvents(AnimatorSet.java:1142)
>       at android.animation.AnimatorSet.startAnimation(AnimatorSet.java:1227)
>       at android.animation.AnimatorSet.start(AnimatorSet.java:729)
>       at android.animation.AnimatorSet.start(AnimatorSet.java:684)
>       at android.animation.StateListAnimator.start(StateListAnimator.java:188)
>       at android.animation.StateListAnimator.setState(StateListAnimator.java:181)
>       at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:21105)
>       at android.widget.TextView.drawableStateChanged(TextView.java:5283)
>       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.drawableStateChanged(AppCompatButton.java:156)
>       at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:21160)
>       at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18379)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
>       at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:335)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:391)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:195)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:540)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$5(RenderTask.java:666)
>       at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Note: App is working perfectly on Moble but Layout preview is not displaying the layout and that is the issue.

**Thanks in advance.**

**Edit**
I have done the following solutions but nothing happens and error persists.

- Invalidate Cache and Restart
- Clean Build
- Revert the material design to version 1.0.0

Comment: What's the Version of your Android Studio??

Comment: Android Studio version 3.4.2

Comment: Try changing your **AppTheme** from Preview window.

Comment: When I change the AppTheme from the design screen, it shows the layout but colors not showing properly. Plus when I shift to text mode from design mode and open a side preview screen then still the error persist and no preview is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh the layout after following changes:

1) Remove the line `tools:context=".home.Home"` from parent layout in file **activity_home.xml**.

2) Change name of class **Home** to **HomeActivity** in file **HomeActivity.java**.

3) Resync project with gradle files.

### Edit:

This isn't due to errors in XML/backend code. It is due to a bug in Android Studio which can be tracked  [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132316448) it is apparently fixed in version 3.6 Canary 3 (API 29 and material_version = '1.1.0-alpha08') as well.

Comment: Done with all the steps but still preview not displayed.