# Android Studio preview goes blank when I add <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>

Tags: android, android-studio, material-ui, material-design

In any Android app that I have developed, I personally prefer the `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` view, rather than the plain `EditText`, just as, in my opinion, it looks *much* nicer in any and every way possible.

The problem, though, with using `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText`, the preview in Android Studio goes blank. It is difficult to design UI when you cannot preview it except by compiling, and running the actual app on the device.

Here is my `fragment_world.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".WorldFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textField"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Hello, world!" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see, nothing out of the ordinary is going on here. The preview showed just fine before I added the `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` view into the layout. Now, the preview goes blank. If I switch to a different tab, and switch back, I can see the outlines of each view in the layout, but it quickly reverts back to its previous, blank state.

I have attempted to create a new, clean project, with nothing in it except this layout here:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textField"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hello, world!" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

That did not work, the same exact thing happened.

Comment: Have you enabled these dependencies? material, appcompat?

Comment: @C.F.G
My build.gradle file implementations:
`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'`

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/q/57518952/6576302

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually an issue with Android Studio itself. Upon trying the same setup in the Canary 6 version, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem, the issue starts from

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
```

for now, I`ve changed the version to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

and it works, as I see in the comments the problem is in the Android Studio, so just waiting for the fix

Comment: The fix is in a newer Canary version, so it will eventually arrive.